# Determine when it's monday by the minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I feel this is a simple question, but there are several factors in play here which make it a bit more complex than it would seem.

For a site, we need to change a page weekly (with javascript/jQuery, no PHP or anything), with the transition being sunday 00:00 AM (from sunday to monday). It is important this happens on that minute/hour, due to page content being relevant for past and next weeks (actions, discounts, product advertisements etc.).

I searched a lot, tried several scripts, and i eventually ended up with this script:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
  var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
  return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
};

var today = new Date();
var currentWeekNumber = today.getWeek();

//Returns weeknumber, content is adjusted through if(weeknumber == 35){etc.}
```

Now this seems to do what i want it to do, but when we tested it last sunday it seemed to initiate (at least) 3 hours too early as far as we could see (oddly enough not too many testers at sundaynight!).

Could anyone help me get underway with a proper script?

Something that adds to my struggle is timezones. I live in Amsterdam (GMT+2), and the visitors will be in the same timezone (Netherlands, the site is not aimed at people outside this zone).

Another thing that adds to the complexity for me, is that i am unable to test this more than 1 time a week. So any help with that would already be handy.

**Summary:** I need to change webcontent every week at sunday->monday 00:00 AM and a script to help me do that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getDay() //returns 0-6 for Sunday to Saturday
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
var seconds = d.getSeconds();
var time = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
if(n==1 && time=='00:00:00'){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't be able to see the difference between different weeks, would it? Just between wether it's sunday or monday. It's important to know which week we're in as well.